# What is the equivalent of "git rev-parse HEAD:directoryPath" in JGit

Tags: jgit

I tried this - but it does not give the same result as command line:

```
           ObjectId headID = repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
            RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(headID);

            try (TreeWalk walk = new TreeWalk(repo)) {
                walk.setRecursive(true);
                walk.setFilter(PathFilter.create("directoryPath"));
                walk.reset(commit.getTree());
                if (!walk.next()) {
                    return null;
                }
                ObjectId id = walk.getObjectId(0);
                return ObjectId.toString(id);
            }
```

Comment: Looks good at first sight. What is returned? You may also try the shorthand `TreeWalk.forPath(repo, "directoryPath", commit.getTree())`. It returns a TreeWalk already positioned on the requested path.

Comment: TreeWalk.forPath(repo, "directoryPath", commit.getTree()) did help!
with my code i had to add enterSubtree() for walking into directoryPath:
                if (!walk.next()) {
                    return null;
                }
                while (walk.isSubtree() && !projectDir.equals(walk.getPathString())) {
                    walk.enterSubtree();
                    walk.next();
                }
                if (walk.isSubtree()) {
                    ObjectId id = walk.getObjectId(0);
                    return ObjectId.toString(id);
                }